# RaspberryPi does not connect to network after channel change on the router

Tags: networking, access-point

We have a RaspberryPi 3 running Raspbian 4.9.35 On startup the RaspberryPi creates an Access Point with fixed ip to allow devices to connect to it in order to configure it. After the device is configured it connects to the Home Network Wifi. We use *hostapd* to span the access point and *wpa_supplicant* to connect as client to the Home router simultaneous on the on board wifi device.

The problem occurs after the Home router changes channels. The RaspberryPi is not able to connect to the Home router on the new channel.

We have tried to : ifconfig wlan0 down And then ifconfig wlan0 up

And it doesn't help

Restart of the RaspberryPi does not help either.

The problem occurs only when the access point (wlan0_ap) is enabled, but we need to have the access point enabled.

Comment: I'm not following. So you are setting up the wireless to work as an access point **and** also want it to connect to a wireless network? I don't think that's going to hold water.

Comment: Do you use *hostapd* for the acccess point? Do you use *wpa_supplicant* for the client connection to the remote access point? Do you use both together on the on board wifi?

Comment: @ingo , yes we use hosapd and wpa_supplicant

Comment: Do you use both together on the on board wifi? I mean, do you have two physical devices, e.g. the on board wifi and a usb wifi dongle, or do you use only the on board wifi for both, the access point and as client to connect to the Home Network Wifi?

Comment: @Ingo , yes, we use both together on the board wifi , only one physical device for both

Comment: I don't understand "Restart of the RaspberryPi does not help either". How do you connect to it in the first place? Is there only one fixed channel it can connect to?

Comment: @Ingo The wlan0 doesn't change channel after restart , and doesn't connect to the home network

Answer (score 3):

You are using *hostapd* to create an access point together with *wpa_supplicant* to connect as client to your home router. This can be done with the build in wifi device. It is known that the device can only use one frequency so *hostapd* will always use the frequency with that *wpa_supplicant* is connected to the home router. *hostapd* is configured in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`. There must be set a channel (frequency) but it doesn't matter. *hostapd* will ignore that and span an access point with the same channel that the raspi is connected to your home router.

For changing the channel on the connection to the home router I have found at [Raspberry Pi Zero W Simultaneous AP and Managed Mode Wifi](https://blog.thewalr.us/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/):

> I read multiple sources claiming that the channel you use here must match the channel that your wlan0 iterface is using for its WiFi connection, as reported by iw dev. In my testing, it looks like the RPi’s AP will dynamically change channels to match whatever channel the wlan0 interface is currently using. I watched this happen in real time by rebooting the WiFi AP the RPi was using, forcing it to roam and switch to another AP in my house. In the process, wlan0 switched from channel 11 to channel 6, and ap0 did the same, without losing connectivity.

Seems you have to checkup your configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Ingo for the reference. I will check the configuration